# Create and display snippets in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, code-snippets

I am creating an application that will create and display snippets from news articles at the top of an HTML page.

I am trying to get the article headline and the first sentence of each article create a snippet and display in the headlines at the top of the HTML page demonstrated in the code below but is not working.

The article headline and the first sentence of each article that I want to move to the top of the HTML page should be like this example as fallow

*What a load of Bull! . . . Chinese Kung Fu Masters are seeking the ultimate opponents.
Has Anybody got a Tissue? . . . A Hawaiian monk seal got an eel caught in its nose ― and it wasn’t the first time for these endangered creatures.
Dog Pulls Off Spectacular Save During Argentina Soccer Match. . . . A pooch invaded the pitch during a Federal A league match between Juventud Unida and Defensores de Belgrano over the weekend.
Nobody Beats The Laws of Nature . . . A 69-year-old Dutch man has failed in his attempt to legally declare himself 20 years younger.*

I also tried to use this function to create the snippets and display but also didn't work.

```js
const create = function(t,v,p){
let n = document.createElement(t)
n.innerHTML = v;
p.appendChild(n);
return n;
}

let ul = create('ul')
```

Here I tried to create with a div and then loop through all the headlines and h4 and display.

```js
function create() {
    let headings = document.querySelectorAll('.newsarticle h4'); // Get H4s
    let menu = document.createElement("div"); // Create DIV
    let menuUList = document.createElement("ul"); // Create UL
    menu.appendChild(menuUList); // Append UL to DIV
    for (let i = 0; i < headings.length; i++) {
        let menuUListItem = document.createElement("li"); // Create an LI for each H4 text
        menuUList.appendChild(menuUListItem); // Append the LI to the UL



        let linkText = headings[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue; // Find the text content of each H2
        let menuText = document.createTextNode(linkText); // Create a text node out of each H2 text
        menuUListItem.appendChild(menuText);
        
headings.forEach((hTag) => {
        create('li', hTag.textContent + ' . . . ' + hTag.nextElementSibling.textContent, menuUList);
     });

        document.body.insertBefore(headings[i]); // Insert the text anchor before headings  
    }
    document.body.insertBefore(menu, document.body.firstChild); //Insert completed menu into HTML
}

window.onload = create;
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>JavaScript</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/styles.css">

</head>

<body>
 <div id='wrappermain'>
  <h1>Bizzare News Mash Up</h1>
  <section id='headlines'>
   <h2>Bizzare News Summary</h2>
  </section>
  <section id='news'>
   <h3>News Stories in Full</h3>
   <article class='newsarticle'>
    <h4>What a load of Bull!</h4>
    <p>Chinese Kung Fu Masters are seeking the ultimate opponents.</p>
    <p>Several times a week, kung fu teacher Ren Ruzhi enters a ring to spar with a bovine opponent around
     five times his weight and capable of killing him.</p>
    <p>Ren’s mixing of martial arts and bullfighting worries his mother, but the 24-year-old has never been
     hurt. Besides, he says, grappling with a snorting bull is exciting.</p>
    <p>It symbolizes the bravery of a man,” Ren told Reuters in Jiaxing in China’s eastern province of
     Zhejiang.</P>
    <p>Unlike Spain’s more famous sport, the Chinese variant of
     bullfighting involves no swords or gore but instead fuses the moves of wrestling with the skill and
     speed of kung fu to bring down beasts weighing up to 400 kg (882 lb).</p>
    <p>“Spanish bullfighting is more like a performance or a show,” said Hua Yang, a 41-year-old enthusiast
     who watched a bullfight during a visit to Spain.</p>
   </article>
   <article class='newsarticle'>
    <h4>Has Anybody got a Tissue?</h4>
    <p>A Hawaiian monk seal got an eel caught in its nose ― and it wasn’t the first time for these
     endangered creatures.</p>
    <p>The Hawaiian Monk Seal Research Program posted a startling pic of the poor pup on Monday, and the
     National Oceanic
     and Atmospheric Administration Fisheries provided more details in a post on Wednesday.</p>
    <p>The administration said it has seen the same “eels in noses” phenomenon nearly a handful of times in
     the last few years.</p>
    <p>“We don’t know if this is just some strange statistical anomaly or something we will see more of in
     the future,”
     the NOAA wrote.</p>
    <p>The agency has two theories on why it happened in this case: A cornered eel was trying to defend
     itself or escape, and
     wound up in the seal’s nose. Or the seal could have swallowed the eel first and regurgitated its
     prey out the wrong way.</p>
   </article>
   <article class='newsarticle'>
    <h4>Dog Pulls Off Spectacular Save During Argentina Soccer Match.</h4>
    <p>A pooch invaded the pitch during a Federal A league match between Juventud Unida and Defensores de
     Belgrano over the weekend.</p>
    <p>Juventud Unida were already comfortably ahead against Defensores de Belgrano in their league clash
     when the dog
     made his unexpected cameo.</p>
    <p>Belgrano looked on course to go four goals down when their goalkeeper kicked the ball against a
     Juventud player,
     who then took a shot towards the empty net.</p>
    <p>But in the nick of time, a dog came out of nowhere to race across the line and nod the ball away from
     goal.</p>
    <p>Unfortunately, the dog was unable to inspire a comeback as Juventud went on to win the match 3-0.</p>
   </article>
   <article class='newsarticle'>
    <h4>Nobody Beats The Laws of Nature</h4>
    <p>A 69-year-old Dutch man has failed in his attempt to legally declare himself 20 years younger.</p>
    <p>Last month, motivational speaker Emile Ratelband filed a lawsuit against the Dutch government
     requesting that his
     date of birth be switched from March 11, 1949, to March 11, 1969.</p>
    <p>On Monday, a court in the Netherlands city of Arnhem rejected his age-changing application, saying
     that while Ratelband
     “is at liberty to feel 20 years younger than his real age and to act accordingly,” actually changing
     the birth certificate
     is not possible.</p>
   </article>
  </section>
 </div>
 <!--moved to the bottom to load the page faster-->
 <script src="scripts/snippet.js"></script>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: In the first snippet, you call `create` without providing `v` or `p`, the latter of which is quite necessary to the functioning of the function (as indicated by the error shown in the console when you Run code snippet). In the second snippet, you try to set a `makeNavMenu` function to the `window.onload`, but above that you've named your function `create`.

Comment: true. I see I missed the function call in the window.onload. thx. I fixed now but still not working. The first snippet function I just set the t,v,p as an argument to create the Li then append the UL to LI then display the text in the innerHTML returning the Li

Comment: The first snippet doesn't work because you only provide one parameter, `'ul'`, when you call `create`: `let ul = create('ul')`. Since you don't provide `p`, the call to `p.appendChild(n)` fails, as `p` is undefined. You need to call it like `let ul = create('ul', nulll, document.body);` or something like that.

Comment: I did some changes, I replaced the `window.onload`  with the `addEventListener` and inserted the `'ul', null, document.body in the ul = create()` as you said also I used the `insertBefore nextSibling`- link https://jsfiddle.net/lmanhaes/yqoxcLfb/19/ unfortunately still didn't work.